# numpy get row index where elements in certain columns are zero

Tags: python, numpy

I want to find indexes of row based on criteria over certain columns

So, something like:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.random.rand(4, 5)

x[2, 2] = 0
x[2, 3] = 0
x[3, 1] = 0
x[1, 3] = 0
```

Now, I want to get the index of the rows where either of columns 3 or 4 are zeros. How can one do that with numpy? Do I need to make multiple calls to `nonzero` for each column and combine these indices using a `set` or something like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `np.where` first `array` within the `tuple` is row `index`

```
np.where(x[:,[3,4]]==0)

Out[79]: (array([1, 2], dtype=int64), array([0, 0], dtype=int64))
```

Comment: Thank you and I guess one could use the set to remove duplicates.

Comment: @Luca stack with numpy , so you can using np.unique